# How to send Laravel POST to external API

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm working on a local application and I want every time the user record a new item, I send the information to another remote application to save it.

I setup a Controller in the remote application to handle the post and save it.

In my local controller:

```
$client = new Client;
    $r = $client->post('https://url-of-the-remote-app/api/store/fiche', 
    ['json' => [
        "access_token" => csrf_token(),
        "request" => $request
    ]]);
```

But I have this error.

> lient error: `POST https://url-of-the-remote-app/api/store/fiche`
>   resulted 
>       in a `419 unknown status` response:

Comment: Use curl for the same https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: which guzzle version you are using ?

Comment: guzzlehttp/guzzle: "6.3"

Comment: `access_token" => csrf_token()` is wrong, the access_token is a token given to you by the provider of the api

Comment: could you let us know what is the `POST https://url-of-the-remote-app/api/store/fiche` so we may help, if there is no harm in make it public !

Comment: @TarekBaz I'm the provider of the API. how can I generate an Access Token?
my /api/store/fiche is very simple:
    $fiche = Fiche::create( $request->all() );
    return response()->json($fiche)

Comment: **iF** it is a route that should be a used by an authenticated user so you could fellow the docs or a tutorial to setup an api-token-based-auth with laravel (use passport) **ELSE** you do not need to apply the auth middleware for this route.